# Routing Messages from Azure Event Hub to Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub

Is it possible to automatically route/redirect events from *Azure Event Hub* to *Azure Service Bus*

[image]

Basically i want to have a system-wide (used by the entire company) event hub and a service bus for a specific system (System X) (which is composed of multiple services)

Instead of developing a service that would read from *Azure Event Hub* and write to *Azure Service Bus* (System X Event Gateway), i would like to know whether there is a way to configure something like this in Azure.

I know that it is somewhat possible with *Azure Logic Apps*, but i doubt its performance, i need the messages to be routed immediately and in *Logic Apps* the default interval is 3 minutes.
I also don't know whether it is the best way to do it, there might be another Azure product that i'm unaware of.

What do you suggest?

Comment: You may not be able to do this out of box if you are not using Azure Logic Apps. Event grid doesn't support Service Bus yet . In this situation Best way is to write and subscribe azure function and redirect the event to service bus. Other out of box option i am not aware either.

Comment: @Imran Will azure function yield better performance than azure logic apps? It's just that doing it with azure logic apps is extremely simple, not to mention, I don't even have to write any code.

Comment: The only difference in term of Logic Apps and function is Declarative vs programming approach , and they both are serverless. Not sure of Logic apps , but Azure functions are triggered model and you should get your events redirect in near real time.  If you can achieve this with logic apps go for it.